# How to upgrade Composer? - Composer update failed: "/opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer" could not be written

Tags: php, linux, composer-php, packagist

Background:

- It was reported on 27 April 2021 that Composer has a vulnerability that impacts PHP.
- https://blog.packagist.com/composer-command-injection-vulnerability/
- https://portswigger.net/daily-swig/php-package-manager-flaw-left-millions-of-web-apps-open-to-abuse
- Recommended action: Update to Composer 2.0.13
- Composer - https://getcomposer.org/

Server Environment:

- Linux
- Shared web hosting

These are the steps I took:

**Step 1: Log on to Terminal and find out the composer version I am using**

```
composer -vvv about
```

Result:

> Running 2.0.6 (2020-11-07 11:21:17) with PHP 7.3.27 on Linux / 4.19.150-76.ELK.el6.x86_64

**Step 2: Run command to update Composer**

```
composer self-update
```

Result: Error Message

> Upgrading to version 2.0.13 (stable channel).
>
> [Composer\Downloader\FilesystemException]
> Filesystem exception:
> Composer update failed: "/opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer" could not be written.
> rename(/opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer): failed to open stream: Read-only file system
>
> self-update [-r|--rollback] [--clean-backups] [--no-progress] [--update-keys] [--stable] [--preview] [--snapshot] [--1] [--2] [--set-channel-only] [--] [< version>]

**Step 3: Find out the permissions for /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer**

```
ls -l /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer
```

Result:

> -rwxr-xr-x 1 bin bin 2192976 Nov 10 13:37 /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer*

```
stat /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer
```

Result:

> File: `/opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer'

> Size: 2192976         Blocks: 4288       IO Block: 4096   regular file

> Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 266192      Links: 1

> Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    1/     bin)   Gid: (    1/     bin)

> Access: 2021-05-02 02:40:36.937400521 -0600

> Modify: 2020-11-10 13:37:13.000000000 -0700

> Change: 2021-04-14 16:25:27.129945713 -0600

Answer (score -1):

You cannot upgrade composer on a shared hosting environment. You could download an entirely new instance of composer to another folder but you may run into restrictions. You should contact the hosting provider and let them know. Alternatively since you are on cPanel you can contact cPanel.

Additionally you should read the exploit more carefully. Do you have Mercurial? This exploit might not even apply to you.

The second exploit link you listed is not related to you, as you are on a higher version than the exploited one.